# Stripe + Plaid + Flutter best practises

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, plaid

Which of these procedures are safer?

Directly obtain a `stripe bank account token` (generated from the client-side `plaid client`) and send that token to my server for processing

Or

Send the `plaid account token` (generated from the client-side `plaid client`) to my backend server and retrieve the `stripe bank account token` remotely?

The [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/ach) says I provides steps for the latter however the [plaid-client flutter api](https://pub.dev/packages/plaid) (unofficial) provides a method to obtain the `stripe bank account token` directly.

Obtaining it directly would save server resources, however I would not do it at the expense of user security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never have a secret client-side since anyone could view it and make requests as if it was you.

You should be following Stripe's documentation here. You obtain a plaid token client-side first, then you send this to your server. There, you can securely use your secret to exchange this for a Stripe token, and then use Stripe's API to save the bank account on a Customer.